# Upper-bounding the out-going degree of a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, partitions

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$, I'm looking for a way to orient its edges in a way that will bound its out degree.

For example, I can bound the graph's out-degree by $\approx 2\cdot a(G)$, where $a(G)$ is $G$'s arboricity by simply assigning all vertices that have at most $2\cdot a$ unassigned neighbours to a set. Then, marking these vertices as assigned and moving on. It can be shown that in each phase, enough vertices are being assigned. This will give me an orientation with an out-bound of $\approx 2\cdot a(G)$.

(I did not extend regarding the above in too much detail, as I only meant it as an example for what I am looking for)

However, I'm looking for other ways, to build a different orienation with an out-degree as small as possible. This out-degree does not have to depend on the arboricity, it can depend on other parameters of the graph (free to choose), aiming for a lower bound as small as possible.

**Edit:** The orientation must be acyclic (or such that can be transformed to an acyclic without increasing its degree too much).

Comment: The problem is NP-complete for the most general version of the problem, however, a _5-bounded [acyclic orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyclic_orientation)_ can be obtained in linear time for any planar graph (Chrobak, M., & Eppstein, D. (1991). Planar orientations with low out-degree and compaction of adjacency matrices. Theoretical Computer Science, 86(2), 243-266.).

Comment: Do you mean that bounding the out-degree by a constant is hard? For my question, also if the bound is small, but depends on a parameter of the graph it might be ok (Such as $2\cdot a(G)$, only its not small enough, its hard for me to define what is considered small enough for me, but I'd like to see several possibilities, if they exist).

Comment: @PålGD: With the acyclicity requirement, the problem is equivalent to finding the graph's degeneracy, which can be done in linear time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of finding an *acyclic* orientation with minimum outdegree is equivalent to finding the [degeneracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory)) of the graph, which can be solved optimally in linear time. The following algorithm due to Matula and Black is copied from the above-linked Wikipedia page:

- Initialize an output list $L$.
- Compute a number $d_v$ for each vertex $v$ in $G$, the number of neighbors of $v$ that are not already in $L$. Initially, these numbers are just the degrees of the vertices.
- Initialize an array $D$ such that $D[i]$ contains a list of the vertices $v$ that are not already in $L$ for which $d_v = i$.
- Initialize $k$ to 0.
- Repeat $n$ times:

  - Scan the array cells $D[0], D[1], \dots$ until finding an $i$ for which $D[i]$ is nonempty.
  - Set $k$ to $\max(k,i)$
  - Select a vertex $v$ from $D[i]$. Add $v$ to the beginning of $L$ and remove it from $D[i]$.
  - For each neighbor $w$ of $v$ not already in $L$, subtract one from $d_w$ and move $w$ to the cell of $D$ corresponding to the new value of $d_w$.

At the end of the algorithm, $k$ contains the degeneracy of $G$ and $L$ contains a list of vertices in an optimal ordering for the coloring number.